# Angular returning of a single user property from the database

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript

I am trying to build an app using `ASP.NET` as the Back End (API) and `Angular` to build the Front End of my app.

Here are my controllers in the API to get the list of the users respectively a single user from the database.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> Get()
    {
        return await _dbContext.Users.ToListAsync();
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<User>> GetUser(int id)
    {
        return await _dbContext.Users.FindAsync(id);
    }
```

In `Angular` in the component's `.ts` file I've added the following code:

```
export class Component1 implements OnInit {
    users: any;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getUsersList();
    }
    
    getUsersList() {
        this.http.get('https://localhost:44357/api/').subscribe(response =>
        {
          this.users = response;
        }, error => {
        console.log(error);
        })
  }
```

In the `.html` file of the component I have then added the following snippet and managed to return a list of all names of the users in the database.

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <select class="form-select">
                <option *ngFor ="let user of users">{{user.name}}</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

My problem is now that I want to return a property (the **name** property for example) from a single user in another component.

Here is the .html file:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <form>  
        <input class = "textbox" type="text" name="Name" value="0"> 
    </form>
</div>
```

And here is the `.ts` file of that component:

```
export class Component2 implements OnInit {

  user: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUser();
  }

  getUser() {
     this.http.get('https://localhost:44357/api/{id}').subscribe(response =>
     {
       this.user = response;
     }, error => {
       console.log(error);
     })
   }
}
```

I want to return the property of a single user( that is stored in the database) in the textbox. Any ideas how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `ngModel` to your input control:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <form>  
        <input class = "textbox" type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.name" name="name"> 
    </form>
</div>
```

And also add `FormsModule` to your `AppModule` class

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Hi, this throws an error because I need an ID as the parameter of my getUser() function. Do you know how I should rewrite the function in order to get the name of the user?